# Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue using strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to create a function that counts the number of times a specific character is used in a string.The portion that is giving me the error is:

```
s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned howMany(char c, const string & s);
string changeCase(const string & s);

int main() {
    char z;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter char and string: ";
    cin >> z;
    getline(cin, name, '\n');
    cout << howMany(z, name) << endl;
    cout << changeCase(name) << endl;
}

unsigned howMany(char c, const string & s) {
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (c == s[i]) { count++; }

            if (isupper(s[i])){ s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
            count++; 
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared s as const.  You can't change it.